# Access forbidden in LAMP

Tags: apache

I'm using LAMPP server, with the following `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName frontend.dev
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/ucmd/frontend/web/

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ucmd/frontend/web/">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using a symlink for ucmd folder created like this:
`ln -s ~/ucmd /opt/lampp/htdocs`

I assigned it 755 permissions, recursively. Copying the folder to htdocs doesn't work either, and fails with 403. I have restarted apache countless times, and even tried setting permissions to 777, it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using symbolic links in Apache requires that you have:

- Options FollowSymLinks
- access to the location the symbolic links points to

Since you're using a symling in your home directory(~), you must add read permissions for the following:

- /home
- /home/***username***
- /home/***username***/ucmd

Comment: That fixed it! I only had permissions set to the target directory, not the entire path!